# I am having an issue with react router as my url is getting updated on clicking on it but the page is not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I am having an issue with react router as my url is getting updated on clicking on it but the page is not getting rendered  but when I reload it at that specific url then it renders the content whereas I want it to be rendered as soon as I click on the link

this is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Nav from './Nav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Nav/>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/about' render={About} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my Nav.js

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
import './App.css';

function Nav(){
    return(
        <Router>
        <nav>
            logo
                <Link to="/about">
                About
                </Link>
                <Link to='/shop'>
                shop
                </Link>
        </nav>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Nav
```

this is my About.js

```
import React from "react";

function About(){
    return(
        <div>
            About Page
        </div>
    )
} 
export default About
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either wrap the `App` component with `BrowserRouter` or, wrap the `App`  component with `Router` component that accepts a history prop.

**Index.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Nav from './Nav';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import About from './About'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    
      <Nav/>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/about'>
        <About/>
      </Route>
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router , Link } from "react-router-dom"; 
import './App.css';

function Nav(){
    return(
        
        <nav>
            logo
                <Link to="/about">
                About
                </Link>
                <Link to='/shop'>
                shop
                </Link>
        </nav>
        
    )
}

export default Nav
```

Since, **Nav.js** and other components using `Routes` are wrapped within the app component which is further wrapped within `BrowserRouter` in **index.js**, you don't need to include `Router` in each component having `Route` or `Link` components.

Comment: Thanks man it worked. Really appreciated

Comment: If my answer helped you fix your issue, please consider marking the [answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Thank you.